# Number of ways that for integers $l$, $m$, $n$ and real $x$: $\sqrt{l^2 + m^2 + n^2} < x$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $l$, $m$, $n$ be positive integers and $x$ a positive real number. Then, what is the number of ways that $\sqrt{l^2 + m^2 + n^2} < x$, i.e. what is the cardinality of the set

$$S_x = \left\{ \{l,m,n\} | \sqrt{l^2 + m^2 + n^2} < x  \right\}$$

as a function of $x$? (In the case that the order of the three integers does not matter.)

What if the order of $l$, $m$, $n$ did matter, i.e. $(0,0,1)$ is different from $(0,1,0)$?

(Remark: I don't have the slightest ability to tackle this question. It arose in the context of a Physics problem and I thought it might be interesting to ask.)

Comment: You might want to adjust your notation: both $\sqrt{1^2+2^2+2^2}$ and $\sqrt{1^2+1^2+2^2}$ are less than $\pi$ and presumably distinct in your count but both $\{1,2,2\}$ and $\{1,1,2\}$ are really $\{1,2\}$

Comment: I doubt there’s a nice and neat answer to this... the value $|S_{x+1}|-|S_{x}|$ is equal to the number of ways to express $x^2$ as a sum of three squares, which I know is expressible in closed-form, although I think the formula is quite complex.

Comment: Well, the $2$-dimensional analog to this problem doesn't seem to have a (finite) closed form, so I doubt the 3-dimensional case has. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem

Comment: Is there perhaps an upper/lower bound? (Or an approximate solution?)

Comment: For the case where $l,m,n$ are any integers (not just positive) and order matters, the linked paper says:
$$\frac{4\pi x^3}{3}+O(x^{3/2}) $$
To obtain the positive-integer triples, you divide by $8$, also substract the solution $(0,0,0)$. If you want unordered triples, you also have to take care of that.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0108.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an estimate.

These are the points
$(l, m, n)$
such that
$l^2 + m^2 + n^2 < x^2
$.

This is the 3d version
of a famous 2d problem
of number of points in a circle.

An approximation is
the volume of a sphere
of radius $x$
which is
$\dfrac43 \pi x^3
$.

Anything more is beyond me,
but I'm sure someone
will come up with
some references.

Comment: The approximation is for the limit of large $x$ right?

Comment: Yes indeed .....